# Dealing with bimodal residuals

Tags: regression, linear-model, residuals, qq-plot, nonparametric-density

I want to run linear models to understand the effect of single predictors on an outcome. This is quite straightforward, but I am facing a situation where my residuals appear to be bimodal.
I can't find a way to deal with this. Am I interpreting this right? What should be my next course of action?

[image: QQ Plot]

[image: Residual Density]

Comment: Do you think there is a reason for these two modes? For ex. can a new variable help explain these differences, such as sex or something?

Comment: It could be. I have data from males/females and also data from two countries. 
However, I also have state and city-level data (which aren't evenly balanced). Could you explain to me what exactly it means to have bimodal residuals, and whether this needs to be transformed prior to running the regression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a made up example just for illustration of when you might expect such results. Consider a sample of 200 people, 100 F and 100 M, we are interested in modeling their height. F are on average 160 cm tall, M are on average 180 cm tall. We model the height with their weight, which in this case is similar between F and M, they both weigh 70 kg on average (unrealistic, but just to show why). If we run a model without including sex, so just `height ~ weight` then we get the following results

```
df=data.frame(
  "height"=c(rnorm(100,160,3),rnorm(100,180,3)),
  "weight"=rnorm(200,70,10),
  "sex"=factor(c(rep("F",100),rep("M",100)))
)

mod1=lm(height~weight,data=df)
plot(mod1,which=2)
hist(mod1$resid,breaks=20,main="")
```

[image]
[image]

The reason being that a linear model will fit the mean regression line, which happens to be right in the middle of F and M, which is not really useful because we do not even have many people in that height range. This can also be seen from another plot.

```
plot(mod1,which=1)
```

[image]

We can fix this by including sex in the model, which will differentiate between these two groups of data. These two groups basically originate from two different distributions, and so we probably should include this into the model, so that it will be able to estimate additional parameters to account for this. Running another model with sex included we get

```
mod2=lm(height~weight+sex,data=df)
plot(mod2,which=2)
hist(mod2$resid,breaks=20)
```

[image]
[image]